# An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I cant find what is wrong, why I have System.UriFormatException

```
string url = Url.Action("SendConfirmationEmail", new { orderid = newOrderDDD.ID.ToString()});
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyHelpers.CallUrl(url));
```

And this is my helper that I use

```
public static void CallUrl(string serviceUrl)
{
    var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
    req.GetResponseAsync();
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect that `HttpWebRequest.Create` does not support a relative uri. You should inspect the exception in the debugger for the details of the exception.

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005367/getting-full-url-of-action-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: so how get correct url

Comment: It work, thank a lot - string url = this.Url.Action("SendConfirmationEmail", "Cart", new { orderid = newOrderDDD.ID.ToString()}, this.Request.Url.Scheme);