# URL.Action link is not build correctly when creating anchor tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url.action

I'm building an anchor link using `Url.Action` in my view.
When built, it does not contain controller method:

```
function showDetails(data) {

    var link = "@Url.Action("Index", "Detail")" + "/" + data;       
    var returnText = "<a target='_blank' href='" + link + "'>" + data + "</a>";

    return returnText;
}
```

When displaying the link in console: `console.log(link)`, it gives me `/Detail/123` instead of `/Detail/Index/123`

This is how the routing is defined in the `RouteConfig.cs`

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I added the following per your suggestion befor `Default` route

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "TicketDetail",
        url: "Detail/Index/{data}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Detail", action = "Index", data  =UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post *all* of your routes, including any attribute routes and area routes.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a combination of problems.  First

> it gives me /Detail/123 instead of /Detail/Index/123

Because `Index` is the default route so `/Detail` is actually 100% correct.

```
//                                            Default = Index
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

There is no reason to add `Index` to the URL as Asp.Net sees it.  It does add `Detail` because `Detail != Home`.  If you changed the default to `Detail` it would give you just `/`.  [If you want to force the url you can create your own helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784004/209259) (from the duplicate question/answer).

```
public static string AbsoluteAction(this UrlHelper url,
  string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null)
{
  string scheme = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;

  return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
}
```

> You can then simply use it like that in your view:

```
@Url.AbsoluteAction("Action", "Controller")
```

Secondly, because you are adding `data` on the client side as a path parameter instead of query parameter it doesn't work.  You could keep your code exactly as is if you did:

```
var link = "@Url.Action("Index", "Detail")" + "?id=" + data;
```

or

```
var link = "@Url.Action("Index", "Detail")" + "?data=" + data;
```

not sure what your method is expecting because you didn't include it in the relevant code.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing nothing, the problem is the default route registered by the ASP.NET.

I don't know which version you are using, but in my example I used ASP.NET MVC4 VS2015, and in the file RouteConfig.cs on method RegisterRoutes there is the default route registered, in some versions you will find this code on the Startup.cs.

Note the code bellow:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The default value for te action parameter in an URL {action} is "Index", so ASP.NET assumes that if you suppress this value you are inferring you want to access this action, so it follow the rule suppressing the default values from URL to understanding unnecessary.

To solve your problem you can register a new route as the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DetailUrl",
            url: "Detail/Index/{data}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Detail", action = "Index", data = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The ASP.NET will generate the linked based on the first match rule.

Comment: I will try that. But it is strange, though. I thought it would build my `/Controller/Method/` path by default when using `Url.Action("method","controller")

Comment: Not necessarily, the Route works with match case, note when you create a default project and just run it, the application starts with an url like "http://localhost:port/" and as you can see the controller "home", and the action "index" was suppressed, because is the default values.

Comment: In other words, ASP.NET will infer to match with the correct URL

Comment: Now, when have the correct url, it still does not show details page. Looks like my data parameter is null. Should I keep it optional? I needs to be there?

Comment: Can you post the code of the new registered route?

Comment: Just posted the changes

Comment: What is the data parameter type?

Comment: I fixed that by removing `data` parameter from both `url` and `defaults` sections. Can that change in the `RouteConfig.cs` file possibly break other urls built in the application?

Comment: Post the Index operation please, it must be something like Index(int? data)

Comment: Data parameter is the id of the item to open a details page for

Comment: so you can solve put the parameter as nullable, or just removing it from the route template. Hope this helps.