# An elegant way of showing URL on page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

Is there an elegant way of showing URL on page using ASP.NET MVC3 .The method I'm looking for should accept contollerName,actionName and routeValue(similiar to @Html.ActionLink() by arguments)

**e.g.Code:**   Here's the link: @*thatMethod*("Show", "Post", new { Post = 0 })

**e.g.Result:** Here's the link: http://localhost:3120/Post/Show/0

**EDIT 1:**
I dont wan't it to be hyperlink,just plain text.

**EDIT 2:**
It needs to show domain ("http://localhost:3120" in previous example)

Comment: Provided I understood your need properly, you should check this out: http://urlrewriter.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434604/how-to-i-find-the-absolute-url-of-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc) is an even better solution.

Comment: No I don't want it as hyperlink,forgot to mention.Thx for help

Comment: I tried just as you told, and i got "/Post/Show/0" as a result,but I wanted to get "http://localhost:3120/Post/Show/0" .Any idea?

Comment: Hmm I realized that, in the mean while I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434604/how-to-i-find-the-absolute-url-of-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc) what just does what you want, if you add routeValues as a parameter

Comment: Can you post that last one as a new answer so I could accept it as an Answer? Great,Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html Helper extensions.

**Html Helper class**

```
public static class HtmlHelpersExtensions
{
   public static string ActionLinkText(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName,object htmlAttributes, string spanAttributes)
  {
     TagBuilder spanBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
     spanBuilder.InnerHtml = linkText;
     spanBuilder.Attributes.Add("class", spanAttributes);

     return BuildAnchor(spanBuilder.ToString(), string.Format("/{0}/{1}", controllerName, actionName), htmlAttributes);
  }

  private static string BuildAnchor(string innerHtml, string url, object htmlAttributes)
  {
     TagBuilder anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
     anchorBuilder.Attributes.Add("href", url);
     anchorBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
     anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = innerHtml;

     return anchorBuilder.ToString();
   }
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.ActionLinkText("Your Text", "Show", "Post", new { @title = "Your Text" }, "").Raw()
```

This may help you.