# How to convert url path to full or absolute url in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing Web Application using ASP.NET MVC in C#. But I am having a problem with retrieving full or absolute url. In ASP.NET MVC we get url like this. `Url.Content("~/path/to/page")`. It will return `"path/to/page"`. But what I want to do is I have a string like this - `"~/controller/action"`.

Let's consider my website domain is www.example.com. If I use `Url.Content("~/controller/action")`, it will just return "controller/action". I want to get `"www.example.com/controller/action"`. How can I get it?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434604/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-url-of-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc): `Url.Action("action", "controller", null, Request.Url.Scheme)`?

Answer (score 14):

**If you can use the Controller / Action Names...**

You should use the [`Url.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232(v=vs.118).aspx) method for this.

Typically, `Url.Action()` will return something similar to what you presently expect when provided with just the Controller and Action names :

```
// This would yield "Controller/Action"
Url.Action("Action","Controller");
```

However, when you pass in the protocol parameter (i.e. `http`, `https` etc.) then the method will actually return a complete, absolute URL. For the sake of convienence, you can use the [`Request.Url.Scheme`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme(v=vs.110).aspx) property to access the appropriate protocol as seen below :

```
// This would yield "http://your-site.com/Controller/Action"
Url.Action("Action", "Controller", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FKchok).

**If you only have a relative URL string...**

If you only have access to something like a relative URL (i.e. `~/controller/action`), then you may want to create a function that will extend the current functionality of the `Url.Content()` method to support serving absolute URLs :

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string AbsoluteContent(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string contentPath)
    {
        // Build a URI for the requested path
        var url = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, urlHelper.Content(contentPath));
        // Return the absolute UrI
        return url.AbsoluteUri;
    }
}
```

If defined properly, this would allow you to simply replace your `Url.Content()` calls with `Url.AbsoluteContent()` as seen below :

```
Url.AbsoluteContent("~/Controller/Action")
```

You can [see an example of this approach here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/08pjvb).

Comment: I am sorry. This could not solve my problem. This is good answer but. What I want is I want to convert string like "~/Controller/Action" to full url.

Comment: I've updated the answer now that I realize that you wanted to actually use the relative URL. Let me know if you run into any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

The following will render a full url, including `http` or `https`:

```
var url = new UrlHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var fullUrl = url.Action("YourAction", "YourController", new { id = something }, protocol: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
```

**Output**

`https://www.yourdomain.com/YourController/YourAction?id=something`