# how to create absolute url in view of asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

View

```
<a href = "@Url.Action("myaction","mycontrol",new{mycate= item.cate})>
<a>
```

when server run it will transfer below html

```
<a href="/mycontrol/myaction/mycate">
</a>
```

how to let VIEW show absolue url like this

```
<a href="192.168.1.1:8555/mycontrol/myaction/mycate">
</a>
```

i read below the url , this need create another class to create url.

[How to convert url path to full or absolute url in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329956/how-to-convert-url-path-to-full-or-absolute-url-in-asp-net-mvc)

have any another way to create absolue url

**another way => add some code in view**

View

```
@{string url = "192.168.1.1.:8080"}
<a href = "@url@Url.Action("myaction","mycontrol",new{mycate= item.cate})>
<a>
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9833745/4225626)

Comment: You need to concatenate your string with @url.action and then put that variable in href

Comment: you mean like this
<a href = 192.168.1.1:8080 "@Url.Action("myaction","mycontrol",new{mycate= item.cate})>
<a>

Comment: i solve it , thx a lot