# How to get current url in view in asp.net core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In previous versions of asp.net, we could use

```
@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

But it seems it's changed.  How can we do that in asp.net core 1.0?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120222/get-raw-url-from-microsoft-aspnet-http-httprequest

Comment: @DavidG It appears that you can now use UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(Re‌​quest)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You have to get the host and path separately.

```
 @Context.Request.Host
 @Context.Request.Path
```

Comment: This will not report the correct url if you app is sitting in a virtual directory. You will need to prefix the **Request.Path** value with the **Request.PathBase** value if there is one. This applies to almost all the other answers to this question as well.

Comment: What is this `@` between the two strings? could you explain it?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: that's razor view syntax.

Comment: For razor pages I had to use `@HttpContext` instead of `@Context`. For partial views `@Context` works. Did i forget an using?

Comment: There is an easy way in MVC 
`Url.Action("Action", null, null, Request.Url.Scheme);` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434604/how-do-i-find-the-absolute-url-of-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You'd need to add `Request.QueryString` to the end as Request.Path doesn't include the query string

Comment: `Url.Content("~/.....")  ` it will translate to the home app path

Answer (score 149):

You need scheme, host, path and queryString

```
@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}", Context.Request.Scheme, Context.Request.Host, Context.Request.Path, Context.Request.QueryString)
```

or using new C#6 feature "String interpolation"

```
@($"{Context.Request.Scheme}://{Context.Request.Host}{Context.Request.Path}{Context.Request.QueryString}")
```

Comment: How do you get the fragment, say http://test.com/abc#123, how do you get the #123 fragment from the request?

Comment: @fanray You can't. Browsers are not sending URI-fragments to the server

Comment: Consider using [UriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netcore-2.2) to build urls.

Answer (score 122):

You can use the extension method of `Request`:

```
Request.GetDisplayUrl()
```

Comment: This works if you add `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` then `@Context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()`

Comment: still getting - Request does not exist in the current context

Comment: Keep in mind the intellisense summary for this function says `Suitable only for display. This format should not be used in HTTP headers or other HTTP operations.` Based on this, I think @tmg's solution is best (perhaps wrapped in your own extension method).

Comment: if you want it in the same type of Url object as it used to be you can do this once you have the display url: var uri = new Uri(displayUrl);

Answer (score 24):

This was apparently always possible in .net core 1.0 with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions`, which adds extension to `HttpRequest` to get full URL; [GetEncodedUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getencodedurl?view=aspnetcore-1.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_Extensions_UriHelper_GetEncodedUrl_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_).

e.g. from razor view:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
...
<a href="@Context.Request.GetEncodedUrl()">Link to myself</a>
```

Since 2.0, also have relative path and query [GetEncodedPathAndQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getencodedpathandquery?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_Extensions_UriHelper_GetEncodedPathAndQuery_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_).

Comment: thank you for including the @using statement

Answer (score 19):

Use the **AbsoluteUri** property of the Uri, with .Net core you have to build the Uri from request like this,

```
 var location = new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Request.Path}{Request.QueryString}");

 var url = location.AbsoluteUri;
```

e.g. if the request url is 'http://www.contoso.com/catalog/shownew.htm?date=today' this will return the same url.

Comment: Things like this make me think .Net Core is a step backwards in some ways. Is this better than Request.Url in Asp.Net in some way that I am unable to imagine?

Answer (score 12):

You can consider to use this extension method (from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` namespace:

```
@Context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()
```

For some my projects i prefer more flexible solution. There are two extensions methods.

1) First method creates `Uri` object from incoming request data (with some variants through optional parameters).
2) Second method receives `Uri` object and returns `string` in following format (with no trailing slash): Scheme_Host_Port

```
public static Uri GetUri(this HttpRequest request, bool addPath = true, bool addQuery = true)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
        {
            Scheme = request.Scheme,
            Host = request.Host.Host,
            Port = request.Host.Port.GetValueOrDefault(80),
            Path = addPath ? request.Path.ToString() : default(string),
            Query = addQuery ? request.QueryString.ToString() : default(string)
        };
        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }

    public static string HostWithNoSlash(this Uri uri)
    {
        return uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
    }
```

Usage:

```
//before >> https://localhost:44304/information/about?param1=a&param2=b
        Request.GetUri(addQuery: false);
        //after >> https://localhost:44304/information/about

        //before >> https://localhost:44304/information/about?param1=a&param2=b
        new Uri("https://localhost:44304/information/about?param1=a&param2=b").GetHostWithNoSlash();
        //after >> https://localhost:44304
```

Answer (score 11):

There is a clean way to get the current URL from a Razor page or PageModel class. That is:

```
Url.PageLink()
```

Please note that I meant, the "ASP.NET Core **Razor Pages**", not the MVC.

I use this method when I want to print the canonical URL meta tag in the ASP.NET Core razor pages. But there is a catch. It will give you the URL which is supposed to be the right URL for that page. Let me explain.

Say, you have defined a route named "id" for your page and therefore, your URL should look like

> `http://example.com/product?id=34`

The Url.PageLink() will give you exactly that URL as shown above.

Now, if the user adds anything extra on that URL, say,

> `http://example.com/product?id=34&somethingElse`

Then, you will not get that "somethingElse" from this method. And that is why it is exactly good for printing canonical URL meta tag in the HTML page.

Comment: The cleanest so far!

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer helped me, as did the comment for it from @padigan but if you want to include the query-string parameters as was the case for me then try this:

```
@Context.Request.PathBase@Context.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery()
```

And you will need to add  `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` in the view in order for the GetEncodedPathAndQuery() method to be available.

Answer (score 8):

```
public string BuildAbsolute(PathString path, QueryString query = default(QueryString), FragmentString fragment = default(FragmentString))
{
    var rq = httpContext.Request;
    return Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(rq.Scheme, rq.Host, rq.PathBase, path, query, fragment);
}
```

Comment: but where are you getting `httpContext` ?  That is not going to work with  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.Request`

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking to also get the ***port number*** out of the request you'll need to access it through the `Request.Host` property for AspNet Core.

The `Request.Host` property is not simply a string but, instead, an object that holds both the host domain *and* the port number. If the port number is specifically **written out** in the URL (i.e. `"https://example.com:8080/path/to/resource"`), then calling `Request.Host` will give you the host domain and the port number like so: `"example.com:8080"`.

If you only want the value for the host domain or only want the value for the port number then you can access those properties individually (i.e. `Request.Host.Host` or `Request.Host.Port`).

Answer (score 4):

```
var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}{Context.Request.QueryString}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to get the URL to use it on the razor side, there is an alternative way to get the home app URL:

## `Url.Content("~/.....")`

### Example

In the following example, I wanted to generate a QR code and display it in an `img` tag src, because of using custom route annotation in the `Action`, I can't use `@URL.Action` so as an alternative solution I use `~` like this:

```js
<script>
    $("#imgCode").attr("src", "@(Url.Content("~/generateQr/"))"+ code);

</script>
```

Controller Side

```cs
[Route("/generateQr/{code}")]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

ILSpy show how it was done in Microsoft.Owin.dll.

```
// Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest
using System;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the uniform resource identifier (URI) associated with the request.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The uniform resource identifier (URI) associated with the request.</returns>
public virtual Uri Uri => new Uri(string.Concat(Scheme, Uri.SchemeDelimiter, Host, PathBase, Path, QueryString));
```

I wonder why they removed this property.