# Forwarding request via proxy while keeping params

Tags: c#, proxy

I'm trying to create a rudimentary API gateway, that forwards requests to api services.  In this example, there are 4 query string params, that would need to be included in the pass.  Is there any way to avoid rebuilding the query string, and simply rerouting the request to the service?

```
public class WipController : Controller
{
    public readonly string BaseServiceUrl = "http://localhost:48535";
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("api/wip/timekeeper/{timekeeper}/clients")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Get(string timekeeper, string endDate, string sortBy, string sortDirection)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var url = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/api/wip/timekeeper/" + timekeeper + "/clients", BaseServiceUrl));

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("There was an error retrieving the set of clients for the timekeeper.");
            }

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Json(new { result });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `var url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks.  That's what i needed.  However, I forgot to specify I was using Core, so I just had to use `Request.Path` and `Request.QueryString`

Comment: Take a look at the AbsoluteUri answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437005/how-to-get-current-url-in-view-in-asp-net-core-1-0