# Layout with dynamic menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a layout for my web application, which loads different menu items based on which language the user has configured on his/her profile and if the user isn't logged in, they also get different links. The list of items is returned to each view.

The problem occurs when I try to combine this with javascript, to make the currently visited link active.

Each time the layout is loaded the menu is overwritten with the following code

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LoggedIn)
 {
   <li><a href="@item.Url">@item.Text</a></li>
 }
```

I tried to use the following code to make the links active.

```
$('li > a').click(function () {
    $('li').removeClass();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
 });
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the className in `$('li').removeClass('active');`! Also, be more specific, `li > a` could be any LI's A...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to render the menu based on the current url and set the active at the moment of rendering:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx You can conviniently get a substring of this

 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LoggedIn)
 {
   @if (item.Url == url)
   {
   <li class="active"><a href="@item.Url">@item.Text</a></li>
   }
   else
   {
    <li><a href="@item.Url">@item.Text</a></li>
   }
 }
```

Comment: Does this work with asp.net core? If so, what do I need to include in the view to make "HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" available?

Comment: You can use [@Context.Request.Host @Context.Request.Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437005/how-to-get-current-url-in-view-in-asp-net-core-1-0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `active` class if present on any `li` and then add `active` to the clicked one.

```js
$('li > a').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    $('li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).parent().addClass('active')
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use your code, I am unable to click on the links at all.

Comment: thats bcoz of `e.preventDefault();` remove this for you

Comment: I see, but I would like the links to be functional. Link a should lead me to a, and then become active. As of now, the problem isn't to make the li active, it is to prevent it from happening until after the new page is loaded (and the layout is reloaded)

Comment: Can u provide me a screenshot or a code snippet that I can look and try to fiddle