# How to get the current url with route values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, request, routevalues

I'm trying to retrieve the current request url with routes values, in order to have a return url with all needed values when reaching my controllers.

I tried `HttpContext.Request.Path` and `HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl()` but it returns something like :

```
/Home/Products
```

What I actually need is to retrive the routes values to have :

```
/Home/Products?id=1
```

Is there a way to achieve that?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```cs
HttpContext.Request.Path + HttpContext.Request.QueryString
```

Or for convenience you can create an extension method like this

```cs
public static string GetCurrentUrl(this HttpRequest httpRequest)
{
    return httpRequest.Path + httpRequest.QueryString;
}
```

Then get current `URL`

```cs
var url = HttpContext.Request.GetCurrentUrl();
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451926/7086678) maybe helpful for you.