# getting the returnUrl with parameters from another controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a 'webshop' where you can buy all sorts of fruits, vedgetables and more. this website can be used in multiple languages.
when the user is looking for a specific item he's using a variable to filter through the items. the url will look like this `localhost/Products?item=AARB`.

If the user changes languages it will return the `returnUrl`. the returnUrl only returns the action method looking like `localhost/Products`. I want it so that the returnUrl also contains the query parameter as it is a lot more use friendly to go back to your searched item when changing languages.

My ProductsController has the following Index Method:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string item = "APPE", int amount = 0)
{
    var CurrentCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    ViewData["amount"] = amount; 
    //Uses the Logged in Username to match the items related to it's RelatieNummer
    var LoggedUser = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
    UserCheck ApplicationUser = _context.ApplicationUser.Where(x => x.CompanyNumber == LoggedUser).First();
    var itemCheck = item != null ? item.ToUpper() : "";
    try
    {
        var currentCat = _context.Categories.Where(x => x.CategoryCode.Contains(itemCheck)).First();

        ViewData["Main_Items"] = FillMainItems(); //This is a different Method which fills Commodity names
        var SearchItem = _context.ZzProducts
            .Where(x => x.RelatieNummer == LoggedUser)
            .Where(x => x.HoofdSoortCode.Contains(itemCheck));
        return View(SearchItem);

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
                
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.Message);
        return View("Error");
                
    }
```

The querystring `item` is the users input. for example: He wants to look for banana's(BANA) or Oranges(MAND). when the user changes the language of the website, this querystring needs to be sent back as well, returning a full url of `localhost/Products?item=BANA` from, what I assume is my HomeController

In my HomeController I have made a method that changes the CultureInfo for the user.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });

    Console.WriteLine("The new CultureInfo is now: " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Hopefully I've made my intentions and code clear enough to help find a solution to my problem :)

**Edit**
I forgot to post my PartialView to show where I send my returnUrl back to the HomeController

```cs
@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();

    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}


//Clickable Flags for CultureInfo
<div id="SelectLanguage" title="@Localizer["Language"]">
    <a asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" asp-route-culture="nl-NL" asp-controller="Home">
        <img src="~/css/Languages/nl.png" />
    </a>
    <a asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" asp-route-culture="en-US" asp-controller="Home">
        <img src="~/css/Languages/en.png" />
    </a>
    <a asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" asp-route-culture="de-DE" asp-controller="Home">
        <img src="~/css/Languages/de.png" />
    </a>
    <a asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" asp-route-culture="da-DK" asp-controller="Home">
        <img src="~/css/Languages/dk.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **add the value of the query string** to the end of the path.

Here is the modified code:

```
var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~" 
    : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value+ Context.Request.QueryString.Value}";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your View you have a Codepart where you define the `returnUrl` you then proceed to give this to your HomeController where you set the language.

you can use`Context.Request.Path` to also find the value of your querystring.

```cs
//Checks if the path is empty. If not, check the value of your QueryString
var parameters = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "" : $"{Context.Request.QueryString.Value }";

    <a asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" asp-route-parameters="@parameters" asp-route-culture="nl-NL" asp-controller="Home">
        <img src="~/css/Languages/nl.png" />
```

You can create a Variable Parameters and do the same thing you did with your returnUrl.
Then in your HomeController you can use both your returnUrl and Parameters.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) });
            
            //If parameters is null, only return returnUrl, else return both
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                var item = returnUrl + parameters;
                return LocalRedirect(item);
            }
            else { var item = returnUrl;
                return LocalRedirect(item);
            }
    Console.WriteLine("The new CultureInfo is now: " + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

[this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437005/how-to-get-current-url-in-view-in-asp-net-core-1-0) helped me understand how to use the Context.Request.Path combined with looking at my own code.