# Get absolute current request url in asp.net core 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

how to get absolute request URL in asp.net core?

in asp.net mvc Httpcontext.request has a property as URL but not available in asp.net core.

I want access to absolute request URL in actionfilter.

Comment: i find the way to get url but stackowerflow not let me to answer. i use UriBuilder to generate absolute URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current url in view in asp.net core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437005/how-to-get-current-url-in-view-in-asp-net-core-1-0). This is obviously from ASP.NET Core 1.0, but the answers remain relevant in ASP.NET Core 5.0 as well. It annoys me that there's no longer a property that returns a `Uri` object, but you can create an extension method that does that for you as discussed in this thread.